# HttpClient GetAsync() not working on Xamarin.iOS as expected

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, async-await, httpclient, mvvmcross

So.. it might seems like a pretty easy thing - send an async http request, right? I have Xamarin project, where its Core project is .NET Standard based project. And I'm using HttpClient from System.Net.HttpClient. The problem occurs when I run the app whether on a real device or on a simulator.

Everything I've found on the internet about this is related to the wrong usage of async/await. Interesting thing is that following code works synchronously, I mean when I use *.GetAwaiter().GetResult()*. But run it asynchronously and the app just freezes. *Try/Catch* does not help either :)

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
try
{
   var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://google.com");//.ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

   return await HandleHttpResponse<T>(response);
 }
 catch (Exception 
 {
    App.LogService.Log(MvvmCross.Logging.MvxLogLevel.Error, () => ex.Message);
    throw ex;
 }
```

Comment: Most likely experiencing a deadlock. Would need to see more code to better identify which caller is making a blocking call.

Comment: Calling this method in the async Initialize method - that one from MvxViewModel.
I've also tried to call ConfigureAwait(false), but does not helped either.

Comment: Show that in the question so we don't have to guess how you did it.

Comment: override public async Task Initialize()
        {
            await UpdateAppSettings();
        }

Comment: Without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that clarifies your specific problem or additional details to highlight exactly what was done, it’s hard to reproduce the problem, allowing a better understanding of what is being asked.

Comment: Help us to help you. Remember those trying to help you are volunteering their time and experience. Do not make it more difficult for them to help you by limiting the information needed to better understand your problem. This statement is solely to help you understand the perspective of those trying to help you.

Comment: I have a MainViewModel which inherits from MvxViewmodel (from MvvmCross framework). The MvxViewModel has virtual Initialize method, which I override in my MainViewModel. In that method I call that one I described in the post. That's it really!

Comment: I understand that, but those are details that should be updated in your post not in comments. The majority of the comments you have posted so far should be updated into your post to make it more understandable. Remember you can see your code. We cannot. Not unless you show it to us

Comment: Here you have an article about deadlocks that may help you find a solution to your particular problem https://michaelscodingspot.com/c-deadlocks-in-depth-part-2/